# Using TOP and getting different result sets

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, top

I am trying to write an efficient query for deleting chunks of data. To this end I hoped to avoid an index scan by using the primary key to get the oldest records. However I'm seeing some unexpected results returned.

I hoped this

```
SELECT TOP 15 OrderID FROM [Order]
```

Would give me the oldest 15 records because I could rely on the primary key incrementing and therefore the order of storage would be low to high in the table.

However, this returns a different result set

```
SELECT TOP 15 OrderID FROM [Order] ORDER BY DateCreated ASC
```

Which seems to be a more accurate but more expensive way of getting the result I need.

Confusingly, this

```
SELECT TOP 15 * FROM [Order]
```

Gives a different set of OrderID s (PK) to this

```
SELECT TOP 15 OrderID FROM [Order]
```

I understand that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189463.aspx explains that order cannot be guaranteed without an ORDER BY clause but expected the PK to order for me and can't explain the differences between the final two select clauses.

Comment: You should show your current `CREATE TABLE` as well as all indexes so that we can fully understand the current structure of the table, most importantly the clustered index. Also, what is OrderID? An IDENTITY column? Can't you just ORDER BY OrderID instead?

Comment: Sorry, yes, missing some important info. Can't really post full table definition. OrderID is an IDENTITY column. A clustered index on OrderID.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the plans. When you use `SELECT *` it probably uses the clustered index, and when you only want one column, maybe there is a skinnier index to use.

Don't "expect" a certain order. If you don't tell SQL Server how to order, then it will use the most efficient way possible, and this can change due to probably more than 20 factors.

**If you want a certain order, SAY SO.** Please read #3 here:

- [T-SQL Tuesday #56 : SQL Server Assumptions](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions)

Also, this post by Michael Swart may be an interesting read:

- [Without ORDER BY, You Can’t Depend On the Order of Results](http://michaeljswart.com/2013/09/without-order-by-you-cant-depend-on-the-order-of-results/)

If you want your second query to be more efficient, you can consider creating an index on `DateCreated` (you may want to include `OrderID` - not sure of the present index structure).

---

For your actual goal of deleting `n` rows at a time, oldest first, and assuming `OrderID` is an `IDENTITY` column (so order create date should roughly align with that), why not use this approach (based on [this great blog post, also by Michael Swart](http://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/take-care-when-scripting-batches/)):

```
-- pick a datetime for the newest row you want to delete
-- let's say you want to delete all orders before Jan 1 2014:

SELECT @MaxOrderID = MAX(OrderID)
  FROM dbo.[Order] -- terrible table name, also always use dbo prefix
  WHERE DateCreated < '20140101';

DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000,
        @LargestOrderProcessed INT = -1,
        @NextBatchMax INT,
        @RC INT = 1;

WHILE (@RC > 0)
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) @NextBatchMax = OrderID
    FROM dbo.[Order]
    WHERE OrderID > @LargestOrderProcessed
    AND OrderID <= @MaxOrderID
    ORDER BY OrderID;

  DELETE dbo.[Order]
    WHERE OrderID > @LargestOrderProcessed
    AND OrderID <= @NextBatchMax;

  SET @RC = @@ROWCOUNT;
  SET @LargestOrderProcessed = @NextBatchMax;
END
```

In order to minimize the impact on the log, you may want to add some additional logic in there, from my blog post [Break large delete operations into chunks](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/03/io-subsystem/chunk-deletes). As for the `dbo` prefix, see [Bad habits to kick : Avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Comment: Thank you Aaron. This is fascinating. I see now my incorrect assumption that having orderID as primary key and clustered index, although it will physically order the data in a table, will not provide reliably ordered retrieval.

Comment: I think the most efficient method for me will be to add and ORDER BY OrderID clause. Michael Swart is approaching this in a very similar manner to me, which is reassuring.